# How can I use Joomla's 'Escape' method if I'm using an abstract class to construct data?

Tags: security

Consider this code for instance:

```
<?php echo MyLib::getSection($row);?>
```

where `MyLib`:

```
abstract class MyLib
{
    public static function getSection($row)
    {
        return '<span title="$row->tooltip">'.$row->text.'</span>';
    }
}
```

But I need to **escape** the values in `$row->tooltip` and `$row->text`. Is there an equivalent of `$this->escape()` that I can call from within the `getSection()` method? If I were to call the static function directly, which class should I address to, to avoid override layers as best as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use direct PHP function:

`htmlspecialchars($row->tooltip, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`